# jshint-loader not working with webpack version 4

Tags: webpack

Trying out & learn webpack & its fundamentals, with version-4. facing some issues with loaders & configuration

webpack configuration is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./app.js', './util.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.es6$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'jshint-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.es6']
  }
}
```

upon `webpack-dev-server`, the error shows up, as follows:

```
ERROR in ./app.js
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'jshint' of undefined
at Object.jsHint (/home/sagar/Documents/mine/gitrepo/webpack_illustration/node_modules/jshint-loader/index.js:63:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sagar/Documents/mine/gitrepo/webpack_illustration/node_modules/jshint-loader/index.js:149:11)
at /home/sagar/Documents/mine/gitrepo/webpack_illustration/node_modules/jshint-loader/index.js:55:5
at tryToString (fs.js:513:3)
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:501:12)
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app.js ./util.js
```

Comment: Open an issue on github. Webpack 4 changed quite a bit for plugins.

Answer (score 8):

Webpack 4 removed this.options in the loader context, jshint-loader just fixed this by removing the code. but there is no build in npm registry yet. you can pull the latest jshint-loader from GitHub, then using 'npm link'

or you can go to node_modules, find the jshint-loader, and modify the code from

```
function jsHint(input, options) {
    // copy options to own object
    if(this.options.jshint) {
        for(var name in this.options.jshint) {
            options[name] = this.options.jshint[name];
        }
    }
```

to

```
function jsHint(input, options) {
    // copy options to own object
    if(this.options && this.options.jshint) {
        for(var name in this.options.jshint) {
            options[name] = this.options.jshint[name];
        }
    }
```

please refer https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-migration-guide-for-plugins-loaders-20a79b927202

github fix: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/jshint-loader/blob/master/lib/index.js line 11

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/jshint-loader/issues/50 looks like there is a pull request to fix it but they will not update the NPM package for some reason.

Comment: until they sort it out I would look at eslint - [eslint-loader webpack 4](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/eslint-loader/) -- good luck

Comment: Follow the link to github fix above. At this point in time they are commenting out two code blocks. I did that, and it worked.